# Area of intersection between two circles with same radius

Tags: geometry, circles, area

I am absolutely sure that there exists loads of other posts about this general type of question. However I could not find one correcting my inevitable mistake.

So I am to find the area of the intersection between two circles with the same radius and the second circles centre on the circumference of the first one.

So I thought that I could make a circle sector by connecting two radii from circle 1 to the points of intersection. This sectors area is $\frac{r^{2}\alpha}{2}$ where $\alpha$ is the angle, in radians, between the two radii.

Using the law of sines the area of the triangle $OP_1P_2$, where $O$ is the centre of the first circle, $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the points of intersection, $r\times r \times \frac{r}{2}sin(\alpha) = \frac{r^3sin(\alpha)}{2}$.

Thus the wanted area is $2(\frac{r^2\alpha}{2} - \frac{r^3sin(\alpha)}{2})$

Now we need to find $\alpha$. We can see a triangle with the sides $r$ and $\frac{r}{2}$ with the angle $\frac{\alpha}{2}$. And again using the law of sines we get $\alpha = \pm \frac{2\pi}{3}+4k\pi$. But this is supposedly wrong, from an answer by Alvin Chen [link](https://www.quora.com/If-two-unit-circles-overlap-in-such-a-way-that-exactly-half-the-area-of-each-circle-is-contained-within-the-overlap-how-far-apart-are-the-centers)

I am sure that if I have done any trivial errors it must be with this triangle and maybe that it really doesn't have the side $\frac{r}{2}$?

Very grateful for a correction of my errors!
Thanks.

Edit: A poorly drawn Here's [image](https://gyazo.com/189eeb05f2bd509f646498666e45507c) of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you accept decision with double integrals, then let's consider 2 circles $x^2+y^2=R^2$ and $x^2+(y-R)^2=R^2$. Area you want calculate is
$$2\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{R\sqrt{3}}{2}}\int\limits_{R-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}\,dx\,dy$$

Comment: I have considered this approach, but I really need to practise my geometry!

Comment: @TreeTreeTree. Can I help you in some way?

Comment: Yeah, I would really like to know if my value for $\alpha$ is incorrect and if so, why?

Comment: Can you add link to your geometric drawing?

Comment: Sure! However it was done in paint, so it will not be to scale.

Comment: As I see $\frac{\alpha}{2}=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Comment: Exactly, this is what I thought from the beginning but I included the unnecessary period. I just got really confused by that other post!

Comment: @TreeTreeTree. Now you have 2 way to calculate same, so to check solution well. Feel free to ask if/when you'll need something more.